# Error during configuring kerberos5 using macports

Tags: installation, macports, kerberos, ncurses

While trying to install libmemcached via MacPorts, I hit the following issue:

```
     libmemcached @0.40 +universal
--->  Computing dependencies for libmemcached
--->  Dependencies to be installed: cyrus-sasl2 kerberos5
--->  Configuring kerberos5
Error: org.macports.configure for port kerberos5 returned: configure failure: command execution failed
Error: Failed to install kerberos5
```

It tells me to look in the log for details. Here's the last bit of the log file:

```
:info:configure checking for setupterm in -lcurses... no
:info:configure checking for setupterm in -lncurses... no
:info:configure checking for tgetent... no
:info:configure configure: error: Could not find tgetent; are you missing a curses/ncurses library?
:info:configure configure: error: /bin/sh './configure' failed for appl/telnet
:info:configure Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_net_kerberos5/kerberos5/work/krb5-1.7.2/src" && ./configure --prefix=/opt/local --disable-dependency-tracking --mandir=/opt/local/share/man
:info:configure Exit code: 1
:error:configure org.macports.configure for port kerberos5 returned: configure failure: command execution failed
:debug:configure Error code: NONE
:debug:configure Backtrace: configure failure: command execution failed
while executing
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:configure Warning: targets not executed for kerberos5: org.macports.activate org.macports.configure org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
:error:configure Failed to install kerberos5
:debug:configure Registry error: kerberos5 not registered as installed & active.
invoked from within
"registry_active ${subport}"
invoked from within
"$workername eval registry_active \${subport}"
:notice:configure Please see the log file for port kerberos5 for details:
/opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_net_kerberos5/kerberos5/main.log
```

It seems to say it's missing `ncurses`. Looks like it's there though, since if I run `port installed` I see these:

```
ncurses @5.7_0
ncurses @5.9_1 (active)
ncursesw @5.7_0
```

Any ideas on how to get around this error?

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar error when installing subversion. Here's what worked for me:

`sudo port install kerberos5`

`sudo port install subversion`

... which for you would be libmemcached

So, what worked for me was to separately install kerberos5. Then, when subversion (libmemcached) is installed it finds it and the bug that causes it to fail when it doesn't find it doesn't happen.

Comment: This is what I get: sudo port install kerberos5
Error: Requested variants "" do not match original selection "+universal".
Please use the same variants again, perform 'port clean kerberos5' or specify the force option (-f).

Comment: Then, sudo port install kerberos5 +universal    
--->  Computing dependencies for kerberos5
--->  Configuring kerberos5
Error: org.macports.configure for port kerberos5 returned: configure failure: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port kerberos5 for details:
(and the same error)